# A table with several subtables?

Tags: tables, matrices

I'm trying to create the following table.[image]

Each subtable represents a symmetric matrix, which is why the upper part is not filled in.

I'm not sure what I need is a table.

Any help would be appreciated.

So far I've tried the code below, but it's no where close. The alignment in the tables is bad.

```
\begin{table}
\parbox{.45\linewidth}{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
a& & \\
a&b&\\
a&b&c\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Foo}
}
\hfill
\parbox{.45\linewidth}{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
d&e&f\\
d&e&f\\
d&e&f\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Bar}
}
\parbox{.45\linewidth}{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
a&b&c\\
d&e&f\\
d&e&f\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Foo}
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please, show us, what you try so far.

Comment: @Zarko I've edited the question to show my attempt so far. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
{\captionsetup{skip=-3ex, font=small}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXX}
\caption*{Period $a$}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}  &           &       \\
a_{21}  & a_{22}    &       \\
a_{31}  & a_{32}    & a_{22}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\]
    &
\caption*{Period $b$}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
b_{11}  &           &       \\
b_{21}  & b_{22}    &       \\
b_{31}  & b_{32}    & b_{22}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\]
        &
\caption*{Period $c$}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
c_{11}  &           &       \\
c_{21}  & c_{22}    &       \\
c_{31}  & c_{32}    & c_{22}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\]      \\

\caption*{Period $d$}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
d_{11}  &           &       \\
d_{21}  & d_{22}    &       \\
d_{31}  & d_{32}    & d_{22}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\]
    &
\caption*{Period $e$}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
e_{11}  &           &       \\
e_{21}  & e_{22}    &       \\
e_{31}  & e_{32}    & e_{22}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\]
        &
\end{tabularx}  \\
}
\caption{Diagonal matrices}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Zarko, I haven't tried to implement your answer yet, due to some time constraints on my part. As soon as possible, I'll give you some feedback. ;)

Comment: Thanks Zarko ;)